# Renewing Certbot Let's Encrypt WILDCARD Certificates in Cron

Tags: cron, debian-stretch, letsencrypt, certbot

I've been searching for a good solution to renew WILDCARD certificates from Let's Encrypt.

It's easy to set up a wildcard certificate:

Apache Debian 9 Stretch:

```
sudo apt-get install certbot python-certbot-apache -t stretch-backports

sudo certbot certonly --cert-name CERTNAME --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d 'DOMAIN.co,*.DOMAIN.co'
```

After the DNS setup, it created the certificate. But now I don't want to deal with it every 90 days for renewal. I've been looking for a good solution for a Cron Job. The problem with most Cron Job solutions is that they are for **non-wildcard** domains.

I like this solution which checks every day if the certificate can be renewed and renews it if it allows itself to:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot renew
```

The problem with wildcard certificates is that it has a DNS setup component and `certbot renew` doesn't work with manual certbot setup.

I am looking for a Cron Job that is like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot certonly --cert-name CERTNAME --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d 'DOMAIN.co,*.DOMAIN.co'
```

But I don't think this will work with the DNS setup.

How can I create a Cron Job to renew wildcard certificates property and efficiently?

Comment: What DNS hosting provider are you using? As with everything else in Let's Encrypt, the usual answer would be "automate it", and Certbot has plugins for many DNS hosting services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by switching to [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) instead of certbot.

Documentation on current versions of certbot (1.30-5) say it can do automated wildcard renewals ([DNS-01](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/)), but Debian buster stable doesn't yet include a version that does (0.31.0-5). I couldn't get past the limitation.

I found acme.sh as easy to implement and more easy to understand that certbot. My DNS provider is Cloudflare. The support across both solutions is good.